# How to limit the scroll range with respect to Another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am Trying to move the fixed Postion Element from top to bottom as  we scroll and to limit the lower most position of that element before the footer element

### HTML

```
<div class="outer">

        <div class="main">

            <div class="left">

            </div>

            <div class="right">
              the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right herethe box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right herethe box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right herethe box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right herethe box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right herethe box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right herethe box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right herethe box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right herethe box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right herethe box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right herethe box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right herethe box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right herethe box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right herethe box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right herethe box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here
                    the box that is scrolled goes right here

                <div id="scrolling_boxI" class="scrolling_box">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="footer">
           Footer goes here
           Footer goes here
           Footer goes here
        </div>

    </div>
```

### Jquery

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var pos = $('#footer').offset();
    var top = pos.top;
     var pos1 = $('#scrolling_boxI').offset();
    var top1 = pos1.top
//    alert(top1+"top1"+top+"top"+$(window).scrollTop()+"scrollTop");

 var topT=   $(window).scrollTop()
  if( topT<top-350-top1)
  {
      for(var i=pos1;i<topT+350);i++)
      {
    $("#scrolling_boxI").stop().animate({"marginTop": (i) + "px", "marginLeft":($(window).scrollLeft()) + "px"}, "slow" );
      }
  }
});
```

### CSS

```
.scrolling_box{

   position:fixed;
   top:50px; 
   left:150px; 
   width:300px; 
   z-index:2; 


}
img{
     border-radius:10px; 
      box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
#footer {
   height:200px;
   background:#000;
   color:#fff;
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

What i Reached Till Now Two Versions But Two Have Drawbacks

- [CHeck For Demo this does the purpose But its too rigid](http://jsfiddle.net/5BHJ7/4/)
- [Check For Demo 2 this works perfect sometimes somtimes not](http://jsfiddle.net/ERQTb/1/)

Comment: Swap `position:fixed` with `position:absolute`. You will have more control over the element. Also, use selectors like: `$('.main').height()` to position the element accordingly.

Comment: Just check with my jsfiddle demo its actually the opposite

Comment: after two months some one took effort and voted down the question without caring to explain why he took some much of his precious time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built something rather close to what you're trying to do. Instead of having the moving element positioned over top, it was on the side. With a little bit of a modification you should be able to get it exactly how you want.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/86Zp7/2/)

Here's how mine works.

```
var parent_height = $(parent).height();
var parent_offset = $(parent).offset().top;
var window_height = $(window).height();
var doc_scroll = $(document).scrollTop();
```

These variables will get you the information you need to find out the proper position of the moving element. `parent` is the element your basing the scroll height off of.

```
var progress = (doc_scroll - parent_offset) / (parent_height - window_height);
```

`progress` is the amount scrolled down the page, relative to your `parent` element in decimal percentage.

```
if (progress < 0) { progress = 0; }
if (progress > 1) { progress = 1; }
```

After setting `progress`, I make sure it doesn't go over (or under!), by doing this.

After this step, our needs differ. I calculate the `margin-top` needed to position it. If you're using `position:absolute;` you will need to use `progress` to set your moving elements `top` value.

Hopefully this helps!